# Rails 3 validates_uniqueness_of works in an unexpected way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR. I'm facing a problem when using validates_uniqueness_of. I've a table with 3 columns:

```
name      || father_name || dob
Vimal Raj || Selvam      || 1985-08-30
```

I've a code in my model like this:

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :dob, :father_name, :name
   validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:father_name, :dob], case_sensitive: false,
                           message: ": %{value} already present in the database!!!"
   before_save :capitalize_name, :capitalize_father_name

   private

   def capitalize_name
      self.name.capitalize!
   end

   def capitalize_father_name
      self.father_name.capitalize!
   end
end
```

It throws error as expected when I insert => "vimal raj, Selvam, 1985-08-30"
But it is accepting the following data => "Vimal Raj, selvam, 1985-08-30" . I was expecting it will throw an error, but unexpectedly it accepts the record and inserts into the db as a new record.

Please help me on how to solve this.

Comment: The scope appears to be case-sensitive no matter what - the case-insensitive appears to only affect the uniqueness question of `:name`, not the scoping. I'm not sure I'd call the surprising, but it would be nice to have a way to do that.

Comment: Please Edit you question first, above you wrote that you have field name, first_name and dob in your table, not father_name.

Comment: I'm sorry Rails Guy. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a one-liner solution, please try this :

```
before_validation lambda {self.name.capitalize!; self.father_name.capitalize!}
```

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Rails Guy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the case_sensitivity is only matching on name, not on father_name.  I would try changing before_save to before_validation so that both name and father_name are consistently the same capitalization when your validation is evaluated.